# JSX no work with nullish operator ? React

Tags: reactjs

I want to show some element but no work ->

```
      { someArray.length > 0 ?? ( 
          <div>
            Test
          </div>  
        )}
```

but this is work ->

```
      {someArray.length > 0 ? (
        <> 
          <div>
              Test
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
           <></>
      )}
```

Why my first block code no work?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _"no work"_, but probably because false _isn't_ nullish - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Okay how to fix this ?

Comment: You already have a version that works, so... use that?

Answer (score 0):

```
{ someArray.length > 0 && ( 
    <div>
       Test
    </div>  
)}
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

x > y will never be null, it will always be boolean.

Maybe you're looking for the **[Logical OR operator (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)**, or **[Logical AND operator (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)**?

```
{ someArray.length > 0 && ( 
    <div>
       Test
    </div>  
)}
```

But since you appear to want to only do something if there are elements in an array, why not just map the array?

```
{someArray.map(
  arrayElement => (
    <div>
      element {arrayElement}!
    </div>
  )
)}
```